# JSON.Net - Reading/Parsing a File of JSON Rows

Tags: .net, vb.net, json.net

My input looks like this:

```
[
{
"somenums": "1",
"someDate": "1.1.2014",
"viewdata": "1119958",
"visitdata": "152452",
"uniquedata": "125873"
},
{
"somenums": "2",
"someDate": "2.1.2014",
"viewdata": "1863752",
"visitdata": "241453",
"uniquedata": "200762"
}
]
```

I haven't been able to find a lot on how to handle a file like this containing multiple rows.  One scrap of info I did find is that Json will deserialize objects enclosed in square brackets as a List.

After fumbling around to get rid of syntax errors I have ended up with the code below but get a runtime InvalidDirectCast exception on the statement `jrrows = DirectCast(JsonConvert.`etc.

```
    If ofd.ShowDialog = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then

        My.Settings.LastJsonFileDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(ofd.FileName)
        My.Settings.Save()

        Dim sr As New StreamReader(ofd.FileName)
        Dim jrrows As List(Of JsonRow)
        jrrows = DirectCast(JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(sr.ReadToEnd), List(Of JsonRow))


    End If
End Sub
End Class

<Serializable()> _
Public Class JsonRow

    Public somenums As String
    Public someDate As String
    Public viewdata As String
    Public visitdata As String
    Public uniquedata As String

    Sub New()  'we need a parameter-less constructor to make it serializable
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: It's not "rows". It's just an array of JSON objects.

Answer (score 1):

In C#...

```
string json=File.ReadAllText(ofd.FileName);
List<JsonRow> mydata = JsonConvert.Deserialize<List<JsonRow>>(json);
```

In VB.NET (auto translated)

```
Dim json As String = File.ReadAllText(ofd.FileName)
Dim mydata As List(Of JsonRow) = JsonConvert.Deserialize(Of List(Of JsonRow))(json)
```